# APK and Java Standard Library and SDK Platform

Tags: java, android

When I analyze an APK, I see classes.dex and it supposed to contain my Java code and it does, why it also contains Java standard Library (java.io.) and the SDK platform (android.app.) which I used to compile the project.

Can anybody explain why are they included?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when we are writing any program we need to import the classes which are needed. So, likewise to run the program, it needs those code. The `java.io` or `android.support` are nothing but some codes written.

Comment: Thanks @Nigam, Okay, I understand that here's the normal scenario where you're writing a hello world program in java and you compile it [ Don't forget you're including import statement in your code ] but the compiled code doesn't have any Java Standard Library [ [JCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Class_Library) ] in it. When you run the compiled class these predefined library is included in runtime, why is this not applicable for Android. And I am not mentioning the Android Support library, I referencing the Android framework's core library and API like Activity, Intent so and so.

Comment: APK file is generated not when you compile. Its generated when we run the program. Obvious thing these core framework codes are attached to the dex. Am I right?

Comment: So are you saying that Android framework is not included in the device by default we have to include the framework while building APK am I Right or not ?, that's why we are mentioning compile SDK version in the build script.

Comment: Yes. The Android device supposed to recognise those classes and do necessary actions. That's why those are added to our application.

Comment: Okay thanks, but It's odd Android OS must have these in it, why are we giving it explicitly ?

Comment: Basically what I can say is the code which we are writing is Java code. So, the Operating System converts this Java code to the low level language code and process it like wise we installed Java in our PC that mean Java is already there in our PC still we are attaching the Java libaries and that codes are also there in the jar.